# "different" as a preposition

Tags: grammar

Is is acceptable to use "different" as a preposition, as you would use "unlike" or "in contrast to", like in the following example?

> Thus, different from previous work, we aim to answer those questions.

Comment: I would for sure use unlike or in contrast to there

Comment: you might be misguided on what a preposition is: "different from previous work" - "from" is the preposition, it governs the noun "work" in relation to the adjective "different"

Comment: Ah, I was describing "different" as a preposition here following the analogy with "unlike". What is the right way to call this kind of use of an adjective to introduce a noun phrase?

Comment: _Different from_ is a compound preposition, if you need to call it a preposition for some reason. What _different_ is, though, is a predicate. Normally a predicate adjective, and a transitive one, since it distinguishes at least two things, which must both be clear, and may both be mentioned. When both are mentioned, the preposition _from_ is normally used for one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus, different from previous work, we aim to answer those questions.

In this sentence, "from" is the preposition:

> [from](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/from?s=t) — (used to express discrimination or distinction): "to be excluded from membership; to differ from one's father."

If you wanted to use "different" as a preposition it would look like:

> Thus, different previous work, we aim to answer those questions.

This is completely ungrammatical.

So, no, you cannot use "different" as a preposition.

---

Your example does have one issue, however. Rearranging the clauses to remove the commas:

> We aim to answer those questions different from previous work.

The more correct form would be:

> We aim to answer those questions **differently** from previous work.

This has nothing to do with the preposition and everything to do with the relationship between "answer" and "differently".

Comment: @TimLymington: Yes, you are correct. I noticed that as soon as I hit submit and have already updated the post. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

"different" was, is and will always be adjective.